# ruby array with subtraction

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I am trying to subtract two values in my array the largest and the smallest. I have sorted them then tried to subtract them but the output is different. I am also trying to use a loop but I keep getting errors. It would be nice to show me what I am doing wrong. thanks

```
numbers = [randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50)]

loop do  
puts "type s to start and q to quit"
input = STDIN.gets
break if input == q
puts numbers.sort.inspect 
puts numbers.first - numbers.last
end   

output:[3, 13, 21, 46] 
18
```

I wanted 46 - 3

Comment: Instead of just saying "it's not working", try to describe the symptoms. Also, `numbers = 4.times.collect { rand(50) }`.

Comment: For starters, `input == 'q'` since `input` is a string.

Comment: @Michael Actually `input == "q\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this instead?

```
numbers = Array.new(10) {|n| rand(50) }
result = numbers.max - numbers.min
puts result
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort method do not overwrite your array. So you end up subtracting the first random number from the last random number.

In this example, use sort! instead.

```
puts number.sort!.inspect
```

This will overwrite your original array.

[Here's](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist) a good blog post that I found some time ago about the so called bang methods (the ones that end with a !).

Answer (score 1):

Some errors:

```
  break if input == q
```

q is a -never defined- variable. Use a String instead:

```
  break if input == "q"
```

`STDIN.gets` includes a `\n`. SO you must compare with "q\n" or `strip` the input.

Depending on your execution, you will see the result after the end. Use `STDOUT.flush` to show the result immediate.

`sort` doesn't change your array. use `sort!`instead. After sort the biggest value is in the end. Instead `numbers.first - numbers.last` you need `numbers.last - numbers.first` (or you need a `reverse.

In total:

```
numbers = [randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50),randomNo = rand(50)]

loop do  
  puts "type s to start and q to quit"
  input = STDIN.gets
  break if input.strip == "q"
  numbers.sort!
  puts numbers.inspect       
  puts numbers.last - numbers.first
  STDOUT.flush
end
```

---

Another version:

```
puts "Push any key unless q to start"
STDOUT.flush
while STDIN.gets.strip != "q"
  numbers = Array.new(5){ rand(50) }.sort
  puts numbers.inspect       
  puts numbers.last - numbers.first
  puts "type q to quit - any other key to repeat."
  STDOUT.flush
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` with bang version.

```
ers.sort!
puts ers.last - ers.first
```